# Large amount of data in scrolled list

Tags: knockout.js

I got problem. I created scrolled List with few objects which are get from REST:

```
<script>
    ...
    that.array = ko.observableArray([]);
    that.getData = function(){
      $.getJson("linkToResource",function(json){
        that.array(ko.mapping.toJS(json));
      }
    }
    ...
</script>
```

and display it in foreach as template:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: array">
  <li data-bind="template: {name: 'my-element-template'}"></li>
</ul>
```

I applied mCustomScrollbar to this ul list.
Every thing goes well until my REST service return big amount of data (2000-20000 rows).

This package of data just kill browser. It have to display 2000-20000 li elements.

I made some research and found something like koGrid which pretty well goes with such amount of data. This plugin display only few elements in Viewport and scroll just change data which should be displayed.

Unfortunatly koGrid doeasn't fit to my problem.

I need srollable list with custom scroll and have posibility to define on template as one row.

Do you know any plugin for knockout which can help me with this trouble?

Answer (score 0):

I've got to be honest, I think that you're asking the wrong question! Why doesn't koGrid fit with your problem? I've not used it, but looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid/wiki/About-Custom-Templates), you can have a custom row template. What exactly is it you want to do that koGrid doesn't do?

Comment: Yes, it's one problem to solve with custom row template. Didn't try but probably it should be able to done. The next problem is scroll. I need custom scroll with css etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found something like giga-scroll https://github.com/mpj/giga-scroll
It's look good, but I have to change normal scroll to custom scroll like in jScrollPane.

There is also support for lazy-loading data.